# basis and Jordan canonial form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P_3$ be the real vector space of polynomials of degree at most 3. Let $T:P_3\rightarrow P_3$ be defined by $T(p)=p''+p$ for all $p\in P_3$. Find a basis $X$ for $P_3$ such that the matrix of $T$ with respect to $X$ is in Jordan canonical form.
Can someone give me clue?

Comment: Do you know how to find the Jordan canonical form of a matrix?

Comment: @awllower  Yes, I also know how to find matrix respect to a certain basis. But I do not know how to make the matrix is Jordan canonical form

Comment: I cannot understand you. You can find the matrix of $T$ under the standard basis first, and then transform that matrix in Jordan form. This gives you a required basis, right?

Comment: @user81235 I hope the added details help you understand. Notice, you could follow the advice of awllower and do the calculation on the matrix, but I think the calculus allows a more efficient solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find $det([T] -\lambda I)=0$ to determine the eigenvalues. Any basis for $P_3$ will do, for example $\beta=\{ 1, x, x^2,x^3 \}$ for which $T(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3) =  2c+6dx+a+bx+cx^2+d^3 = a+2c+(b+6d)x+cx^2+dx^3$ hence $$[T] = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$
Therefore, the eigenvalue is $\lambda = 1$ repeated four times. You can calculate eigenvectors and generalized eigenvectors for this matrix then translate back to polynomials in view of the basis $\beta$. Alternatively, calculate the eigenvectors directly in polynomial notation.

We're looking for as many solutions of $T(f(x))=f''(x)+f(x) = f(x)$ as possible. Clearly that gives $f''(x)=0$ which allows solutions $f(x) = ax+b$. This gives us two eigenvectors. Therefore, we need to find two generalized eigenvectors.

We want them in a chain, $T(f(x))-f(x) = 1$ or $T(f(x))-f(x) = x$. (now I'm guessing, there is no reason given my current calculations that either $1$ or $x$ is attached to a chain). Continuing (with reckless abandon)
$$ f''(x) = 1 \qquad \text{or} \qquad f''(x) = x$$
hence $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2$ or $f(x) = \frac{1}{6}x^3$. I believe, we can use $\gamma=\{ 1, x^2/2, x, x^3/6 \}$ as a Jordan basis. Finally, let's check:
$ T(a+bx^2/2+cx+dx^3/6)=$ 
$$= b+dx+a+bx^2/2+cx+dx^3/6 = (a+b)+bx^2/2+(c+d)x+dx^3/6. $$
it follows that $[T]_{\gamma,\gamma}$ is in Jordan form.

Comment: $$J = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right]$$ according to  $\beta=\{1,x.x^2,x^3\}$, but I do not how to continue.

Comment: @user81235 sorry, I had to step away for a few minutes, that matrix does not look correct. Twice differentiating $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$ yields $2c+6dx$ which suggests for your basis a $2$ and a $6$ should appear somewhere...

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I think the OP meant to say that he has found the Jordan form. He referred to the basis just to convey that he started from that basis, I suppose.

Comment: @awllower and user81235 correct. I misread that comment. Indeed that is the Jordan form which is $[T]_{\gamma,\gamma}$ in my answer above. Thanks for the clarifying comment.

Comment: @awllower and JamsS.Cook, if I have already known the Jordan Form above, how do I continue?

Comment: @user81235 Whether or not you alreayd knew the Jordan form, look into the answer(s). It was the reason you asked the question, was it not?